# Where is the default JavaMailSender Bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to use spring-boot-starter-mail dependecy but when I try to autowire the JavaMailSender Object, my IDE (IntelliJ) tells me I can't autowire that bean.
But it's said in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-email.html) that the bean is created when spring.mail.host is defined... which is the case...

```
    @Service
public class MailService implements IMailService {

    @Autowired
    public JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Override
    public void sendMail(String to, String subject, String text) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(text);
        mailSender.send(message);
    }

}
```

When I create the bean myself only by returning the object (whithout the configuration). He doesn't use any of the configuration set up in the properties file...

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
    return new JavaMailSenderImpl();
}
```

Do I have to create the bean myself with all of the configuration set ?

Comment: You don't need to create any bean for mailsender .just specify mail credential in the properties file

Comment: `spring.mail.host,spring.mail.port,spring.mail.username,spring.mail.password` Add these properties

Comment: I did all these but IntelliJ can't find any bean for JavaMailSender

Comment: Did you add the dependency `spring-boot-starter-mail`?

Comment: yes of course :)

Comment: Then definitely some other issue . For email spring boot expect only dependency and properties . may be you should remove bean and check .

Comment: Can you share error trace?

Comment: Have you actually tried running the application instead of only lookin at the error in the code in IntelliJ? As depending on the version of IntelliJ it might (or might not) detect the Spring Boot auto configured instance, depending on the level of Spring Boot support.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes IntelliJ doesn't autodetect Spring's configuration and it has to be added manually to the project. Go to `File -> Project Structure -> Facets`, and check if you have it configured, otherwise click on `+` button -> choose the module you need.

Also, as [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) suggested, try running your `@Service` bean in a Spring Boot application and check for any exceptions autowiring dependencies. The `JavaMailSender` bean should be created in `MailSenderAutoConfiguration` class inside the `spring-boot-autoconfigure` module.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MailApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    public MailSender mailSender;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MailApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        mailSender.sendMail("joe.bloggs@example.com", "Subject", "Body");
    }
}
```